# is there any perfomance difference in selectors - ['object', context] and ['context object']

Tags: jquery

For example I'm selecting all divs within a section, I can write selectors like this:

1. `$('section div')`
2. `$('div', $('section'))`

Is there any performance difference between these two?

Comment: I guess there is no significant difference between them, Why don't you test that by yourself in JSPERF.com ..? And you might want to add this to your test cases `$('selection').find('div')`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy. jQuery internally converts `$('div', $('section'))` into `$('section').find('div')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first way will be faster than the second, because `$('div', $('section'))` creates two (new) instances of jQuery. But the fastest method will definitely be `$('section').find('div')`, as @Satpal suggested.

Have you read [Optimize selectors](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/) ? A lot of useful information on this page.